# What is the default backpressure strategy in RxJava 1.x?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm in the process of switching an Android Studio project from using RxJava 1.x to RxJava 2.x, and trying to change as little functionality as possible. The project used `Observables`, which in RxJava 1.x are backpressured. In RxJava 2.x, `Observable` is no longer backpressured, but `Flowable` is, so I'm converting my usage of `Observable` to usage of `Flowable`. However, `Flowable.create` requires me to specify a [backpressure strategy](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/BackpressureStrategy.html). Since I want to maintain the same functionality, which strategy does `Observable` in 1.x use?

Comment: All sorts of strategies, depending on the operator. What `Observable`s do you have and why do you have custom `Observable`s (that is `Observable.create()` ones)? v1 `Observable`s map to v2 `Flowable`s now properly handling backpressure. v2 `Observable`s are simply non-backpressured, mostly unbounded buffering operators.

Comment: I guess I wrote my question too quickly. I'm actually not using custom ones, I'm only extending `Observable.OnSubscribe`. So which backpressure strategy for v2 `Flowable` most closely matches v1 `Observable`?

Comment: The question still makes little sense. If you have `Observable.OnSubscribe` that means you are responsible for whatever backpressure behavior you implemented yourself.

Comment: I guess the OP is asking what is the behavior if he didn't implement anything himself. Does it default to drop or buffer or something else.

Comment: I think it throws MissingBackpressureException

Answer (score 0):

The default strategy in RxJava 1.x when implementing your own Observables with `Observable.create` is the equivalent of RxJava 2's `BackpressureStrategy.ERROR`. It will throw a MissingBackpressureException in case the downstream can't keep up.

An example can be found on page 230 of the book [Reactive Programming with RxJava](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920042228.do)